# Subtract two metric results elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, data-visualization, kibana

I have two metric already made.
1st metric represents the number of transactions started by client 
2nd metric represents the number of transactions received by server
I want to get the number of transactions which failed(are sent by client but not received by server) which is simple subtraction
Can I achieve this in Kibana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for Kibana 5.0.0+. It is based on the core Metric-Plugin but gives you the ability to output custom aggregates on metric-results by using custom formula and/or JavaScript. 
You can check more details [Here](https://github.com/ommsolutions/kibana_ext_metrics_vis) .